# How to ask for administrative privilege only once in OSX?

Tags: swift, macos, shell, swiftui, nsapplescript

So I have an app that runs shell command twice, once to disable sleep and then a few moments later to enable sleep. The code looks as follows:

```
  NSAppleScript(source: "do shell script \"sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1\" with administrator " +
                    "privileges")!.executeAndReturnError(nil)
      // and then same code with with '0' instead of 1 to disable it
```

However the issue is I don't want the user to enter their password EVERYTIME they call these commands. It's making for a poor user experience. Is there a way I can grant the entire app admin privilege and run shell commands however I want? Or is there a way to run this shell command without the user authorization?

Comment: The actual approach is way more difficult than it perhaps should be, but the correct way to do this is to install a privileged helper tool (which requires only asking for permission once). Your main app will send an XPC message to the helper tool, and have it disable sleep on your behalf. See [this tutorial](https://www.woodys-findings.com/posts/cocoa-implement-privileged-helper) for a good introduction

Comment: Alexander is right both about the privileged helper tool being the correct way, and about it's being more difficult than it should be.   I have this [fork](https://github.com/chipjarred/SwiftPrivilegedHelper) of a GitHub repo that makes it easier, though its still a pain.   A shell script that the original repo uses fails to emit build errors even though it detects them, so all you get is an Xcode message that it fails with no info about what was wrong.  I changed that to a Swift script that emits errors that show up in your build log. Anyway, you might find it helpful.

Comment: You should be aware that apps that use privileged helper tools can't be sandboxed, and unsandboxed apps aren't allowed in the App Store (except for a very few grandfathered apps or if you can make a very good case for it, which Apple is unlikely to grant).  So if you want to distribute the app to the public, you'll have to do it the old school way, arranging your own website, purchase mechanism, etc...  If it's for you own personal or internal use, that won't be an issue, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: The cynical part of me actually appreciates that this is somewhat hard to do. It takes some pretty good understand to achieve, and sets a barrier-to-entry for apps to be asking for admin access. On another note, I'd recommend [SecureXPC](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SecureXPC), which is a great library for spawning and communicating with privileged helper tools with a nice Swift API (though I'm biased, I contributed to it)

Comment: @ChipJarred Wow, I did not realize how much of a pain this little personal project would be. I wonder if there are any helpers out there that I can just use for my project? Or do I not have any other option than building my own? :/

Comment: @Singh, the GitHub fork I linked to builds an app with a helper tool.  You could use just adapt it with your code.  If as a personal project you don't plan distribute it, it shouldn't be *terribly* difficult since, being your own code running on you own machine, you don't need to be terribly concerned with a lot of signing certificate details.

Comment: If you do that, definitely start with a clone of that project, and put your code/resources into it.  It's possible to go the other way, that is by altering your existing project to build the helper tool, but is more likely to lead to a lot of headaches before you get it right.

Comment: Another option, again assuming you don't care about distributing the code to others, is to just run the app with the necessary privileges in the first place.  I *think* you can do that by setting the owner/group of the executable in the app's bundle.  This is a *bad* security practice in general, but it's *your* code running on *your* machine... so do what you want.

Comment: @ChipJarred I think I get what you're saying. Also sorry for the radio silence; been traveling across the country for work. Anyways, It's being a little hard for me to get a hold of your repo. So I made a clone and I see that there's the app and then there's the app helper. Ideally, would you just want me to replace the app folder contents with the contents of my personal app, correct? Also, I'm not really sure how to incorporated the python code that's linked in the repo to debug the helper code. Basically, I'm very lost. Do you think you'd be able to help in a private chat or smth? :/

Comment: Well no, it's not as simple as replacing the app folder contents.  The app that's there has the code to call to `SMJobBless` to install the privileged helper tool, as well as the the code to call it via XPC. You'd use it as a starting point to adapt to your needs.  You may need to rename things, and then *add* your code.  If the python code is what you want to execute with elevated privileges, you'd do whatever you did to incorporate it into your existing target, but to the helper tool rather than the main app.

Comment: As for helping in private chat, I'm not against it, but I'm not able to allocate a big block of time for anything reliably interactive.  You can write up an [issue](https://github.com/chipjarred/SwiftPrivilegedHelper/issues)  on my repo.  We can continue the conversation there with a lot more flexibility for including code snippets and such.

Comment: @ChipJarred You what I'm thinking. What if I manually pass the password to the sudo terminal command? Since it's mostly for personal use, how can I send the password to the shell command by storing it in keychain? Would that still require the use of a helper?

Comment: When `sudo` asks for the user password, it's not using `stdin`, or any other file handle.  It reads more directly from the controlling terminal (for example, from `/dev/ttys1`).  That's to prevent a malicious process from doing exactly what you're suggesting, and also to prevent the password capture, which might otherwise be possible, for example a pipe routed through `tee` to write the password to a file.  When you invoke `sudo` programmatically from an AppKit app, there is no controlling terminal.  I don't know of a way to do that, though obviously the OS does it for shells.

Comment: You can look at the old Darwin `sudo` source code for [`tgetpass.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-83/sudo/src/tgetpass.c.auto.html) to see how it's reading the password.  That source is old, from when Darwin was open source, but I doubt that particular code would have changed much.